# Fixing questions rather than deleting it?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about an hour ago and it was recently voted to close for the reason it was unclear what i was asking.

Now this is not a complaint about this rather than no comment was given with what part that was unclear.

If you look at SE meta for world building we are on 9.9 questions a day and we want to reach 10 - a good way to reach the last one is maybe using comments to fix questions instead of just "pretend not to care" and close it.

I requested an explanation in comments but it seems like the "pack mentality" on this site bought it another vote without explanation.

- How do i go about this ?
- How do i improve my question without feedback ?

Answer (score 2):

Please link the question in your post.

If you are unsure why it was closed posting here on meta, or asking in chat can help get you answers.

We generally try to provide comments as to the thought of those closing but sometimes it doesn't happen.

Generally speaking people are more than happy to help you review a closed question and keep in mind that closing a question doesn't mean it is gone.  Closure is there to avoid answers stacking up against a question that may need to drastically change (thus negating the validity of the answers).  so at its most basic we are trying to keep question quality high and not waste people's time answering a question that is likely going to change.

Comment: The post wasn't closed, it was just voted to be closed, my point was in general, trying to fix something before discarding it. Explain why one makes such as decisions.

Comment: @Magic-Mouse to re-iterate that is the exact purpose of closing a question, to improve it.  The problem with not closing a question that needs work is potentially wasting people's time answering when the question may need significant rewriting.  Closure is not a commentary on the person or saying a question isn't worth having, simply that something should change before the community gets to far into things.

Comment: In short Closure \= Discarding

Comment: If you vote to close a question without giving feedback about why someone closed it, it looks like it would be because one wants the question removed not because one wants to improve the content on SE:World Building

Comment: @Magic-Mouse A problem for which I have already offered you a solution.  If you have further concerns about the community feel free to visit chat and discuss them.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat

Comment: @Magic-Mouse Additionally if you click on the close link at the bottom of the question it will tell you what category of closure the votes are against, which can provide at least some direction for improving your question

Comment: So first i have to wait to see if and/or when it gets closed then ask on meta? It seems overly complicated and illogical.

Comment: Me guessing what is wrong with the question, gives an equal or higher chance that i actually removes some of the good parts and just generally makes the question worse than it was.

Comment: I have been attempting to assist you in getting the feedback you claim to be looking for but you appear to be more interested in intransigence.  If you find that you would like assistance please join chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25161/discussion-between-james-and-magic-mouse).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I agree with you that the first to vote to close, or at least one of the first, should consider writing a comment about it directly. As James had it, closing a "non-perfect" question saves time for the answerers, but commenting on a question may save further time for the reviewers.

I usually try to do that, but I'm not sure I'm always clear.

Another point, however, one VTC does not mean it's getting closed. Maybe the others disagree with that vote and the question never gets closed.

Answer (score -1):

Try and geuss why your qeustion was closed - is it too broad, off-topic, etc?

If you can't see the problem, try re-wording it. Perhaps you've phrased something in a way that could be interpreted differently than how you intended it.

Comment: My point here is that it makes perfect sense for me, but not to others - if people combined the close vote with a comment, me and others in the same situation would have a chance to improve the content on this site, rather than just discarding a potential interesting question.